# How to fail a Jenkins job based on pass rate threshold of testng tests

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

We are trying to use Jenkins as our CI/CD solution, and want ability to fail a deployment if our TestNG tests do not meet a set pass rate threshold.

Currently our Jenkins job executes our TestNG tests via maven, thus any test failure marks the build as failed. I.e. anything less than 100% pass rate, will fail the build job.

We want ability to make it configurable - i.e. fail the test job if pass rate is below, say, 98%.

Is this something i can control or configure inside the Jenkins job via some plugin, or is it something i have to code for inside TestNG listeners, i.e. `onFinish()` and set the return value based on the calculated pass rate?

Comment: I found that TestNG Results Plugin has "Thresholds for marking the build as Unstable/Failed:", but i can't seem to get it to work no matter what value i put it, the build always comes up as "Failed".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I have Jenkins fail a build only when the number of test failures changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103565/how-can-i-have-jenkins-fail-a-build-only-when-the-number-of-test-failures-change)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there are some flakiness in your test cases that is causing you to make the build pass even when there are 2% failures?  Otherwise, I'd say anything less than 100% is a build failure.

That being said, how about using [Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/)?

With it, you can fail the build when the unit test success is < 98% (see some example screenshots [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/quality-gates-shall-your-projects-pass/)).

You can also fail the build on other occasions as well.  For example, when the coverage drops below a certain amount or when a critical issue is found.  Plus, you'll get the added bonus of a dashboard that contains all your build related metrics.

You will need to download a plugin called [Build Breaker](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker) that will fail the build when a quality gate is below a certain threshold.

One thing to note is that the Sonarqube folks are recommending that you [don't use this plugin](http://www.sonarqube.org/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/).  Thus, you can also do things like [query the Sonar rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34630044/6606196) and fail the build or wait till they [add core support for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33508793/6606196).

Comment: how to achieve this with new age Jenkinsfiles?