# How to create pass threshold for TestCafe Tests on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, testcafe

We've TestCafe.js UI tests that runs regression suite on Jenkins environment.

We're exploring a way to create a mechanism, wherein we can potentially set certain pass threshold for the test suite to make the Jenkins job status as Pass / Fail.

i.e. if 98% + tests pass then mark the test job as pass.

Under XUnit projects same could be achieved using XUnit test Plugin etc.
Example reference: [How can I have Jenkins fail a build only when the number of test failures changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103565/how-can-i-have-jenkins-fail-a-build-only-when-the-number-of-test-failures-change)

[How to fail a Jenkins job based on pass rate threshold of testng tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884514/how-to-fail-a-jenkins-job-based-on-pass-rate-threshold-of-testng-tests)

[How to not mark Jenkins job as FAILURE when pytest tests fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358519/how-to-not-mark-jenkins-job-as-failure-when-pytest-tests-fail?rq=1)

Is similar possible for TestCafe based tests either through TestCafe customization / through some Jenkins plugin?

Our Jenkins file:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
  environment {
    CI = 'true'
  }

  options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '50'))
    disableResume()
    ansiColor('xterm')
  }

  agent none

  // Define the stages of the pipeline:
  stages {
    stage('setup') {
      steps {
        script {
          cicd.setupBuild()
        }
      }
    }

    // Use the make target to run tests:
    stage('Tests') {
      agent any
      steps {
        script {
          cicd.withSecret(<keys>) {
            cicd.runMake("test")
          }
        }
      }
      post {
        cleanup {
          archiveArtifacts artifacts: "screenshots/**", allowEmptyArchive: true
        }
      }
    }
  }

  post {
    success {
      script { cicd.buildSuccess() }
    }

    failure {
      script {
        slackSend channel: "#<test-notifications-channel>", color: 'bad', message: "Regression tests failed or unstable <${env.RUN_DISPLAY_URL}|${env.JOB_NAME}>"
        cicd.buildFailure()
      }
    }
  }
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestCafe [provides](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/reporters.html) a bunch of specified reporters, which generate a report in the special format. Once produced, CI system (or a plugin therein) can parse a report and perform threshold checks based on the number of failed/passed tests. TestCafe documentation includes an [example with Jenkins integration](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/continuous-integration/jenkins.html). The Jenkins JUnit Plugin used in the example doesn't support set threshold yet: [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2734). But you can try to follow the steps in the guide in a similar way, except using Jenkins xUnit Plugin.